# Laravel HTTP basic authentication not working

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building an API in Laravel and am attempting to use HTTP basic authentication. I've created a user with the email/password combination of `user@gmail.com:testpass`. I'm accessing an endpoint at the following URL which requires authentication: `https://user@gmail.com:testpass@myapp.local/users/2`

When I attach the `auth.basic` route filter to this route, I can successfully authenticate and access the authenticated user's details through the `Auth` class, however since this is an API I want to use stateless HTTP basic authentication, so I wrote my own filter:

```
// Our own auth filter to use onceBasic and return a consistent API response
Route::filter('basic.once', function() {
    $result = Auth::onceBasic();

    if ($result->getStatusCode() === 401) {
        // Unauthorized, return our own response
        return Response::json([
            'message' => 'Bad credentials'
        ], Config::get('status.error.unauthorized'));
    }

    return $result;
});
```

No matter what, the result of `Auth::onceBasic()` here always returns unauthorized, even though the username/password combination I'm sending stays the same. Even if I change `Auth::onceBasic()` to `Auth::basic()` in my filter it still returns unauthorized.

I don't even know where to start debugging this as my filter is essentially the same as the `auth.basic` filter that ships with Laravel, albeit with a bit more code to produce a consistent API output.

Comment: Could you post your user model? Also, is your password in the db hashed?

Comment: Did you solve it? Did you try to change the .httaccess?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PHP FastCGI?

From the official Laravel documentation:

---

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#http-basic-authentication

## A Note On FastCGI

> If you are using PHP FastCGI, HTTP Basic authentication may not work correctly out of the box. The following lines should be added to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

---

I managed to solve it myself this way.